# How can I make the semicolon automatically jump to the end of the line

Tags: xcode4

In xcode I often find myself using the ; series of keys. Is there a way to make the ; jump to the end of the line and then insert a ;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Keyboard Maestro Macros for Mac. It's handy.